# Selected value doesn't work on combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, combobox

I am populating my combobox with these values:

```
private void LoadUnits()
{
    using (FbConnection con = new FbConnection(Properties.Resources.connectionString_EB))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand("SELECT UNITID, UNIT FROM UNITS", con))
        {
            FbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            List<Int_String> list = new List<Int_String>();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                list.Add(new Int_String { _int = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]), _string = dr[1].ToString() });
            }
            unit_cmb.DataSource = list;
            unit_cmb.ValueMember = "_int";
            unit_cmb.DisplayMember = "_string";
        }
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

And I have created a simple button with this:

```
private void save_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    unit_cmb.SelectedValue = 1;
    unit_cmb.SelectedValue = product.unitId; //When debugging unitid is = 1
}
```

Problem is that when I press button with only first line, it select first item, when I put that line inside `LoadUnits()` as the last line it doesn't select it (LoadUnits is last method inside OnLoad() function).

Second problem is that when I use only second line (which I need to use) it doesn't select it not even in button even when `product.unitId = 1`

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cytqz.png)

My first thought was that maybe I do not have `selectedValue` of `1` in my combobox so I set this:

```
private void unit_cmb_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(unit_cmb.SelectedValue != null)
    MessageBox.Show(unit_cmb.SelectedValue.ToString());
}
```

and poof, when I manually select first item, it's selected value IS 1 so there IS item with value of 1 but for some reason I cannot select it with program.

Comment: The first item will already be selected, what is your expectation when an item is "selected" and what is not happening?

Comment: It is not selected. Combobox is empty just if I have done `selectedIndex = -1;`

Comment: @Crowcoder look at edited post around button function

Comment: I'm now having trouble following the question. You say it now works in the click event of the button?

Comment: It works as I would expect, here is a minimal example: https://github.com/crowcoder/SelectedValue47121470 .

Comment: `unit_cmb.SelectedValue = 1;` will work if `DataSource` contains value of `1`in property of `ValueMember`. Notice that given value for `SelectedValue` should be same type as type of property given in `ValueMember`, so `unit_cmb.SelectedValue = 1;` should work, for `unit_cmb.SelectedValue = product.unitId;` check that type of `product.unitId` is same type (`int`).